# Where I can find Microsoft.DirectX assembly to reference

Tags: c#, .net, directx, .net-assembly

I am wondering where I can find `Microsoft.DirectX` assembly to reference?

It seems like MS Windows 7 has DirectX installed but I cannot find this assembly using Reference Manager Window of Visual Studio 2015.

Any clue what should be installed?

Comment: DirectX is unmanaged (native), if you want to reference a managed DirectX wrapper then you'll need to install a library for that. I'd recommend SharpDx.

Comment: The .NET 1.1 version was the last one, discontinued after that.  The last DirectX SDK that still had was [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3035).  I think, it is getting hazy.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that link is broken.  I"m trying to use Microsoft.DirectX  and missing. I can't install sharpdx slimdx or silk.net. I need something that runs and compile as close to native windows 10 22h2 without update or any extra download or cloud access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft.DirectX` is the deprecated Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies that date back to the early 2000s. They are deployed by DXSETUP from the legacy DirectX SDK. They are also not compatible with .NET 4.0, and only support Direct3D 9. In other words, they are ancient and don't use it.

Instead you should use [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/).

See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx)

Comment: Any clue how to detect headphones plugged in using those frameworks?